# What arguments are passed to msiexec on uninstall

Tags: windows, registry, windows-installer

I know this information exists but I'm really struggling to find a source.

Where can I find what selecting "remove", from add/remove programs, passes as arguments to msiexec to uninstall the product/package/application?

As far as I am aware it's in the registry somewhere, but I've been unable to locate it.

CLARIFICATION: **I am not looking for individual switches for msiexec**, I'm looking for the location of the specific arguments passed by add/remove programs.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227091

Comment: @RogerRowland I know the individual switches, I do not know exactly what is passed by add/remove programs on uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type the following from a command window to see all the options:

`msiexec.exe /?`

Then to find out which of these is passed for a particular application, go to the following key in the registry and look for the sub-key for the application you're interested in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

For example, on my system, the `Microsoft Visio Viewer 2013` entry shows the following command line under the **UninstallString** key:

`MsiExec.exe /I{95150000-0052-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}`

Answer (score 2):

Add/Remove Programs doesn't use Msiexec.exe or its switches. It uses the MSI API, such as [MsiConfigureProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are not many options. Check in [*Msiexec (command-line options)*, options for uninstalling a product](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_Uninstall) (MSDN).